# Setting sqljdbc driver in Apache Tomcat files

Tags: android, sql-server, apache, tomcat

I am developing an android app that connects with a computer and draws some tables from MS SQL Server. To do that i created a servlet that gets the requests from the android app and do some things to a database of SQL Server. In the beginning i was using eclipse to develope the servlet and everything was fine. Now i want to run the servlet without eclipse. So i installed Apache Tomcat and i added my servlet in there. The servlet is running and the android app connects fine with the servlet. The problem is that when the servlet tries to connect to SQL Server it fails. This is probably because it can't see the jar file of the driver. When i added the driver on eclipse except the jar file i added a dll file named sqljdbc_auth. Does anybody knows where should i put and what files of the driver so that the servlet can do the connection with the SQL Server ???

Thank you very much.